# Getting header files to work with .cpp files

Tags: c++, header-files

I am trying to learn how to use .h files with my .cpp files and any time I run my code I'm getting errors with pretty much every variable that I have.

Here is my .h file:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(
        string firstNames, 
        string lastNames, 
        string socialSecurityNumber, 
        string gender)
        : firstNames(firstNames), 
        lastNames(lastNames), 
        socialSecurityNumber(socialSecurityNumber)
        {}

    string getFirstNames() const;
    void setFirstNames(string aFirstNames);

    string getLastNames() const;
    void setLastNames(string aLastNames);

...

private:
    string firstNames;
    string lastNames;
    string socialSecurityNumber;
    string gender;
};
```

My .cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"
using namespace std;

string Person::getFirstNames() const
{
    return firstNames;
}

void Person::setFirstNames(string aFirstNames)
{
    firstNames = aFirstNames;
}

string Person::getLastNames() const
{
    return lastNames;
}
```

The functions continue for the other variables that you can see in my constructor.  Whenever I attempt to build this it gives me errors such as:

> 'getFirstNames' is not a member of 'Person'
>   'getFirstNames': modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions
>   'firstNames' undeclared identifier

I have just started learning c++ and using header files but come from a Java background and have no idea why these errors are coming up. From the research I've done online this should have worked but obviously it didn't. Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Since you use (std::)string in the header file, you'll need to `#include <string>` in the header file, too.

Comment: Are those three messages the *first* messages the compiler emits? Always start at the first message. As likely as not, any subsequent messages are merely side effects of the first errors. Fix the first errors, and the later ones might go away on the next compile.

Comment: @melak47 I do include string in my header file

Comment: @RobKennedy Yes, those are the first three that appear in the list of 80 some error messages.

Comment: "I do include string in my header file" - that is not what you have shown in the question.  You are including `<string>` in your cpp, when it appears you should be including this in your header (.h) instead (i.e. move the `#include <string>` line to .h).  You will also need the using line in your header too.(i.e. copy the `#using namespace std` line to .h).  Re-compile with those changes.

Comment: @ratsteve adding the using fixed the problem, thank you. do I need that line on every file or how would I know when I need that?

Comment: Best to read up on namespaces.  In short - `string` is in the `std` namespace.  You don't need the using line if you use `std::string` rather than `string`.  If you just write `string` you will need the `using` line.

Comment: @rasteve Okay that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: When you're learning something new (like header files), you should start with the simplest cases you can devise; this example is much too complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `Person` comes before `using namespace std`, so the uses of `string` in the header are not valid.

It's good practice for header files to have no dependencies that must be included first, and to make sure this happens, I always include my local headers before library or system headers:

```
#include "Person.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
```

In your header, make sure it includes what it needs:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H_INCLUDED
#define PERSON_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>
class Person
{
public:
    Person(
          std::string firstNames, 
          std::string lastNames, 
          std::string socialSecurityNumber, 
          std::string gender)
      : firstNames(firstNames), 
        lastNames(lastNames), 
        socialSecurityNumber(socialSecurityNumber)
      {}
   ...
};
#endif
```

**Don't** be tempted to `using namespace` in the header file - that brings symbols into the global namespace and is considered rude to users of the header file.

(BTW, on a i18n issue - be careful about assuming that everyone has both a "first name" and a "last name", and which of those (if either) is a "family name"...)

Comment: You say: "I always include my local headers before library or system headers".  Could you expand on that, as I always do the opposite for readability (std includes, windows/other api includes, my rubbish at the end!).

Comment: If I were missing `#include <string>` from the `Person.h` header file, I will discover it quickly if it's up at the top of includes (and whenever there's a matching implementation file, it _will_ be the first include from that one).  If I always include it last, then the error may be masked for a long time, and it may suddenly stop working when a seemingly-unrelated header (which happens to include `<string>`) is no longer needed.  I like fail-fast development.

Answer (score 2):

As confirmed by the OP (see question comments):

The .h file was missing the following line:

```
using namespace std;
```

The header was using `string`, which is part of the `std` namespace.

Alternatively, replace all `string` instances with `std::string` (therefore, the `using namespace std` line would not be required).

Comment: The "alternative" is the better approach here - don't put using-directives into header files, and _really_ don't pre-depend on a prior using-directive in a header file.

Comment: @TobySpeight - agreed, although didn't want to get into topics like ADL before OP gets an understanding of namespaces in general.